# Adjusting Search Result in SharePoint 2010 Search

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

Hell All,

Is there a way to adjust search result to show documents first?

SharePoint 2010 enterprise search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a custom ranking is possible - but its a science and lots of work.

Here are two posts that tell you about the background and how to customize it:
http://calvisblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/custom-ranking-models-with-sharepoint-2010-background-value-and-administrative-overview/

http://sharepointkaos.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/custom-ranking-model/

I would not touch it if there is no very good reason.